# Enrollment Code is null or change after creation, anyone know how to fix?

Tags: google-classroom

When I request to the classroom api on the v1/courses -> get method it returns "enrollmentCode": null,

but when the course was created it had enrollmentCode not null, and for other courses the enrollmentCode has changed

anyone know why it happens and if there would be a solution.

The courses were created earlier this month

Comment: How did you make the request? Did you try to test with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get)?

Comment: For requests I use google-api-php-client, and yes I use the get method for the details, and the creation was made in same api with method Courses.create

Comment: I am asking because I cannot reproduce the `"enrollmentCode": null` problem, so in order to exclude the possibility of a programming error, it makes sence to see if you can reproduce the issue with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get) feature.

Comment: Enrollment codes can be disabled or reset by the owner of a course through the GC UI.  I haven't found a way to change that setting in the API, but I suspect that's what you're running into.  Disabled enrollment codes would likely show up as null and Reset enrollment codes would change the code.